# For some reason, bulkWrite and arrayFilter are not modifying the document. MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these two subdocuments that are basically structured the same. Each of these documents includes an array of objects name **scheduleInfo**. This array is structured like so.

**EquipmentList**

```
scheduleInfo: [{month: String, hours: Number, frequency: String, equipId: String, uniqId: String}]
```

**AdditionalLabor**

```
scheduleInfo: [{month: String, hours: Number, frequency: String, addLaborId: String, uniqId: String}]
```

This is the code I use to add objects to the **scheduleInfo** in the **equipmentList**

```
 OpportunityModel.bulkWrite(
  equipSch.map(d => ({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { sfOppId: oppId },
      update: {
        $set: { "equipmentList.$[e].scheduleInfo": d.equipSch }
      },
      upsert: true,
      arrayFilters: [{ "e.sfEquipId": d.equipId }]
    }
  }))
)
```

this code executes correctly.
Since the scheduleInfo in additionalLabor is essentially the same thing, this is the code I use to add objects to the **scheduleInfo** in the **additionalLabor**

```
 OpportunityModel.bulkWrite(
  additionalLaborSch.map(d => ({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { sfOppId: oppId },
      update: {
        $set: { "additionalLaborCostInfo.$[e].scheduleInfo": d.schedule }
      },
      upsert: true,
      arrayFilters: [{ "e._id": d.addLaborId }]
    }
  }))
```

**IT DOES NOT WORK** I get a read out showing it found matching documents but did not modify any.

If I get rid of the list filter and use the wildcard $[] it modifies the document, but sets the same schedule for all of the additionalLabor items which is not correct. I have been staring at this code for a while now and I have no idea why it is not working. Please help!

Comment: Your syntax is correct, mongoose has a long lasting bug with `arrayfilters` on 5.4.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Even though it is not comforting. Am I SOL?

Comment: it's not that bad, i just downgraded to 5.3 and it solved it for me.

Comment: That helped. I was able ask a better question and found this. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215167/node-js-mongoose-update-with-arrayfilters)

Comment: Thanks again, life saver.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Tom (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10770370/tom-slabbaert)and actraiser (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2340924/actraiser) I was able to find a solution. Changing my arrayFilters for additionalLabor to

```
arrayFilters: [{ "e._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(d.addLaborId) }]
```

**Works.**