# Mongoose arrayFilters in Bulk update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Struggling to find the equivalent mongoose syntax for the Bulk update with ArrayFilters.

The MongoDB Shell query

```
var bulk = db.coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({}).arrayFilters( [ { "elem.grade": { $gt: 85 } } ] ).updateOne( { $set: { "grades.$[elem].mean" : 70 } } );
bulk.execute();
```

I am unable to find any Mongoose documentation for the above operations.
Did anyone solve a similar problem in mongoose?

I am using Mongoose version 5.9.15, MongoDB 4.2 and NodeJS 12.x

Comment: Mongo shell bulk writes are documented at https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db-collection-bulkwrite

Comment: My question was about the Bulk find and update using arrayFilters. The shell method will work always. But I am unable to find any documentation/examples for Mongoose.

Comment: That documentation is here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.bulkWrite.  This is a different question, but the example code shows arrayfilters being used with mongoose:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528711/for-some-reason-bulkwrite-and-arrayfilter-are-not-modifying-the-document-mongo

Comment: I've seen this before, but that hasn't solved the problem. 
Example: If I want to do a loop in a large array and with each iteration, I have to run an update, at the end of the loop I should call ```bulk.execute();```

Comment: BulkWrite takes an array.  Create an empty array, with each iteration push a new operation onto the array, then pass the array in the call to Model.BulkWrite