# ArrayFilter updateMany query works in console, but fails to work with mogoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoose version 5.11.12, and my mongo cluster is running 4.4.3, and lastly my node is: 10.19.0.

When i try this query:

```
Group.updateMany({},
    {$push:{"threads.$[elem].messages":"hello"}},
{multi:true ,arrayFilters:[{"elem._id":"602645582fa6cb13f8449057"}]},
    (err,result) =>{
        if(err)res.json({error:err}); else res.json({result:result});
        
    }
)
```

it does nothing to the database, and then only returns an unhelpful error object of `{}`.

However when i run the equivalent query of this directly into the mongo console:

```
db.groups.updateMany({},{$push:{"threads.$[elem].messages":"hello"}},{multi:true ,arrayFilters:[{"elem._id":ObjectId("602645582fa6cb13f8449057")}]})
```

and the expected response of:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 2, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

At first, i thought it might be an issue with the ObjectId casting, but i messed with the objectId so it was no longer a valid object id, and it gave the expected objectId error so it seems unlikely that it is that causing the issue.

If it helps, this is what the relevant section of my database looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60264286f5440e114c189212"),
    "members" : [ ],
    "name" : "Computer Science London",
    "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [
                    51.503391,
                    -0.12763
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("60264286f5440e114c189213"),
            "type" : "Point"
    },
    "description" : "A group for computing students to learn, talk and share!",
    "pictureURL" : "/images/computer.jpg",
    "threads" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("602645582fa6cb13f8449057"),
                    "title" : "What is a lambda function",
                    "openingPost" : "I am reading this textbook and it mentions this thing called a lambda function, but it doesnt seem to outline what it is. Can someone help me understand?",
                    "postedBy" : "ElBarto88",
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:07:36.833Z"),
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:07:36.833Z"),
                    "messages" : [
                            "hello"
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("602645af2fa6cb13f8449058"),
                    "title" : "How do i install linux?",
                    "openingPost" : "This server assignment requires i have linux installed, how do install it?",
                    "postedBy" : "ElBarto88",
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:09:03.123Z"),
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:09:03.123Z"),
                    "messages" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T08:55:34.273Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:09:03.123Z"),
    "__v" : 0
```

}

Comment: If you use updatd instead of updateMany is there error still?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi yes unfortunately

Comment: I think mongoose doesn't automatically cast String to ObjectId in a random sub-document of an update document, so it fails to match any elements.  If you explicitly convert that to ObjectId does it behave differently?

Comment: @Joe How do i explicitly convert to objectId?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function

Comment: @Joe , i've casted as your link has told me to do , but i still can't get it to work , and still get back the unhelpful error object `{}`

Comment: im thinking i should just reorganise the schema rather than worry about trying to arrayFilters to work with mongoose if i can not get it done soon.

Comment: check out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215167/node-js-mongoose-update-with-arrayfilters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215167/node-js-mongoose-update-with-arrayfilters)